# Write datatable to SQL Server - add new, update existing, remove missing

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have a SQL Server table that contains three columns:

```
PositionID, MeasureID, ModifiedDateTime
```

In my application I load this data into a `DataTable` and then add and remove rows to/from the `DataTable`. I would then like to write this back to the database.

The way I was doing it initially: delete all matching records for the `PositionID` and then loop and insert command with the all the data (or use Bulk Copy).

Is there a better way to do this more simply?

Comment: The DataAdapter is meant to complement the DataTable.  Add, Update and Delete (not remove) rows, then use the Update method on the adapter to apply *all* changes to the database.  No loops involved.  Gobs and gobs of examples here

Comment: I'll have a look at that one on Monday.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
conn.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Truncate Table SQLTableName", conn);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(conn);
bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "SQLTableName";
bulkCopy.WriteToServer(datatableName);
```

"conn" is your connection to SQL-server.

Comment: The truncate will wipe everything into he table though? I just remove the matching positionID